# Datareader to Datasource OK, but Datagridview displaying only 1 row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datareader

I have a datagridview (with bindingsource, a detail from master) which is populated programmatically from datareader. Datareader successfully retrieves all data and add new rows to bindingsource. However the datagridview is only displaying one row. So in the datagridview it is displaying the last row from the datareader.

When I click Previous button from the bindingnavigator (of the master), then Next, all rows are displayed in the datagridview as if it is refreshing the bindingsource and binding each rows to each datagridview rows. I know I'm missing something here, but not sure what it is.

```vb
Private Sub PopulateDetails(ByVal orderno As String)
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    LoadDB()

    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    cmd.CommandText = "select orderid, pono, cono, styleno, fabriccodeid, custfabriccode, colorid, orderqty, totalbales, uomid, width, " &
                      "weightperarea, yard, gramperyard, size, unitprice, currencycode, deliverydt, remark from tblorderdetails " &
                      "where orderno = @orderno;"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Prepare()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderno", orderno)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    With dr
        If .HasRows() Then
            Dim newRow As DataRowView

            While .Read
                newRow = DirectCast(TblorderdetailsBindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)
                newRow.BeginEdit()
                newRow.Row.BeginEdit()

                newRow.Row("orderno") = OrdernoTextBox.Text
                newRow.Row("pono") = .Item("pono")
                newRow.Row("cono") = .Item("cono")
                newRow.Row("styleno") = .Item("styleno")
                newRow.Row("fabriccodeid") = .Item("fabriccodeid")
                newRow.Row("custfabriccode") = .Item("custfabriccode")
                ''newRow("btncolor") = .Item("colorid")
                newRow.Row("orderqty") = .Item("orderqty")
                newRow.Row("totalbales") = .Item("totalbales")
                newRow.Row("uomid") = .Item("uomid")
                newRow.Row("width") = .Item("width")
                newRow.Row("weightperarea") = .Item("weightperarea")
                newRow.Row("yard") = .Item("yard")
                newRow.Row("gramperyard") = .Item("gramperyard")
                newRow.Row("size") = .Item("size")
                newRow.Row("unitprice") = .Item("unitprice")
                newRow.Row("currencycode") = .Item("currencycode")
                newRow.Row("deliverydt") = .Item("deliverydt")
                newRow.Row("remark") = .Item("remark")

                newRow.Row.EndEdit()
                newRow.DataView.Table.Rows.Add(newRow.Row)

            End While
        End If
        .Close()

    End With
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working for 4 days finding ways to show all rows in the datagridview, and finally resolve it by this:

```
TblorderBindingSource.MovePrevious()
TblorderBindingSource.MoveNext()
```

Apparently the bindingsource needs to be refreshed somehow by the bindingnavigator then only it shows all the added rows in datagridview (with the autogenerated column id of -1,-2,-3...). User can amend these rows then save.

I regret that this does not seems like an "intelligent" workaround, but glad it works somehow.

Answer (score 0):

That is very much the wrong the wrong way to go about it.  After calling `ExecuteReader`, simply call the `Load` method of your `DataTable` and pass the data reader.  That will add all the rows and even the columns if they're not already there.  Alternatively, use a data adapter and call its `Fill` method, passing the `DataTable` as an argument.  Same result.

Comment: "very much the wrong way"? how can it be? if so, it wouldn't be in the API? what if I need to process each record and modify/compute some values before adding to DataTable? what exactly is wrong with Read()?

Comment: @jmcilhinney there's no datatable, but bindingsource. If  bindingsource is casted to datatable: 
`Dim bs = Me.TblorderdetailsBindingSource
Dim dt = CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable)`
It errors out `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.`

Comment: Of course there's a `DataTable`.  What do you think `newRow.DataView.Table` is?  Based on that error message, it sounds like you have bound a `BindingSource` to another `BindingSource`.  That might suggest that you have parent/child data.  Regardless, there's a `DataTable` at the bottom of it somewhere.